# How to properly declare object properties in AngularJS Factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am creating a custom factory in AngularJS that involves declaring an object that has properties that are used in different pages that are used inside an ng-view/ui-router.

```
app.factory('FormValues', function(){
    //Custom factory that allows values to be passed inbetween different pages in the ng-view form. 
    var formVals = {};    

    formVals.custEmail = '';
    formVals.custPhone = '';
    formVals.movieChosen = '';
    formVals.movieTime = '';
    formVals.movieTickets = '';
    formVals.movieCost = 0;
    formVals.concObjects = {};
    formVals.concPurchases = '';
    formVals.concTotalCost = 0;
    formVals.finalCost = 0;
    formVals.tax = 0;
    formVals.subTotal = 0;

    return formVals;
});
```

The factory works as intended, the object properties are being saved, and being used in the different pages.

But, now I'm pretty sure the way I created this factory and using objects is not the most efficient way.  Any tips on I can clean this up and make it more efficient?  I am not even sure if I am supposed to declare empty, blank object properties.

Thanks

Comment: I would probably use $cacheFactory...
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any cleaning up in the code except a small change to the formVals object.

```
app.factory('FormValues', function(){
    //Custom factory that allows values to be passed inbetween different pages in the ng-view form. 
    var formVals = {
      custEmail : '',
      custPhone : '',
      movieChosen : '',
      movieTime : '',
      movieTickets : '',
      movieCost : 0,
      concObjects : {},
      concPurchases : '',
      concTotalCost : 0,
      finalCost : 0,
      tax: 0,
      subTotal: 0
    };    

    return formVals;
});
```